# How to check content of Body Tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check whether content inside body tag is null or not.

Should I use regex for this or is there any other way to handle this like using any jQuery selector?

Your suggestion and help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content within the body-tag will never be null, it could however be empty.

If you use jQuery you could to something like this:

```
if ($("body").html() === ""){
   // Do something if body is empty
}
```

With plain javascript:

```
if (document.body.innerHTML === ""){
   // Do something if body is empty
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I doubt any browser will ever set the content of `document.body` to `null`

Checking for empty string should do it:

```
document.body.innerHTML !== '';
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you can make use of

```
.text()
.contains()
.html()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `document.body` property. For more info  read - [document.body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.body).

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is a good one...you can try something like: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/